# In Flex 4, how to dynamically change Tree rowCount if a node is expanded?

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, tree, count, row

The tree should have a minimum row count of 4 and a maximum of 10 (beyond which it should display the scroll bars). So, I have a tree with rowCount="4" and I want rowCount to change up to "10" depending on the currently expanded nodes. In debug I can see two of the tree's properties which I could use:
- collectionLength
- numberOfRows

But these are not accessible from outside so I can't find a way to understand if the tree is expanded or not.

How can I do this?

Will I have to create a custom MyTree which inherits from Tree? I was trying to avoid this...

Thanks,
Nuno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you already got this figured out but this should be all you need to determine what's open http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#openItems

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much. I believe that would indeed do the trick. Meanwhile we found another solution which keeps track of every item you open and count their children.